# Nginx + uwsgi + Django: Error in url rewriting

Tags: django, url, nginx, uwsgi

I'm trying to deploy a Django project on under a sub path of my institute website.

Let's say server IP is: `X1.X2.X3.X4`.
And `xyz.edu/tnp` *probably* points to `X1.X2.X3.X4/portal/`.

Structure of Django project is like this:

```
.
|-- project
|   |-- app1
|   |-- app2
|   |-- project_nginx.conf
|   |-- project_uwsgi.ini
|   |-- db.sqlite3
|   |-- manage.py
|   |-- media 
|   |-- README.md
|   |-- static
|   `-- uwsgi_params
|-- README.md
|-- requirements
|   |-- base.txt
|   |-- dev.txt
|   |-- prod.txt
|   `-- test.txt
|-- requirements.txt
|-- static_cdn
|   |-- admin
|   .....
```

And my URL scheme in *project/urls.py* looks like this:

```
 url(r'^app1/', include('app1.urls')),
 url(r'^app2/', include('app2.urls')),
 url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

On my local server, following scheme is working perfectly.
* 127.0.0.1:8000/app1/
* 127.0.0.1:8000/app1/login/
* 127.0.0.1:8000/app1/homepage/
* 127.0.0.1:8000/app2/somepage
* 127.0.0.1:8000/admin/

I want to map my URLs on my deployment server, so that
`xyz.edu/tnp/app1` links to `X1.X2.X3.X4/portal/app1` and
`xyz.edu/tnp/app2` links to `X1.X2.X3.X4/portal/app2`
`xyz.edu/tnp/admin` links to `X1.X2.X3.X4/portal/admin`
and so on.

The problem is the suffix `portal` in `X1.X2.X3.X4/portal/`. When I type **xyz.edu/tnp/app1** in browser, the error I'm receiving is

> Using the URLconf defined in portal.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
>
> ^app1/
>   ^app2/
>   ^media/(?P.*)$
>
>   ^static/(?P.*)$
>
> The current URL, portal/app1/, didn't match any of these.

Now I think of two approaches:

1. Manually prepend **portal** to all urls in project/urls.py
2. Drop the prefix **portal** in the portal_nginx.conf file.

First approach isn't working for internal urls. The index page for all apps, i.e. app1, app2 and so on, is working fine but for other urls, they are being rendered as `xyz.edu/portal/login` instead of `xyz.edu/tnp/app1/login`.

Second approach, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133063/how-to-deploy-django-under-a-suburl-behind-nginx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37402852/django-uwsgi-nginx-url-mapping), seems promising, but its not working for me. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. Following are my project_nginx.conf and project_uwsgi.ini files.

**project_uwsgi.ini**

```
[uwsgi]

chdir           = ...
# Django's wsgi file
module          = project.wsgi
# the virtualenv (full path)
home            = ...

# master
master          = true
# maximum number of worker processes
processes       = 10
# the socket (use the full path to be safe
socket          = ...
# clear environment on exit
vacuum          = true
```

**project_nginx.conf**

```
upstream django {
    server unix://.../.../project.sock; # for a file socket
    # server 127.0.0.1:8001; 
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name xyz.edu; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias /usr/share/nginx/.../project/media;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /usr/share/nginx/.../project/static;
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location /portal/ {
        rewrite /portal/(.*) /$1  break;
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        # # the uwsgi_params file you installed
        include     /usr/.../wsgi_param
        # uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /portal/;
        # uwsgi_modifier1 30;

     }
}
```